# Railclone replacement for Blender?

Tags: modeling, add-on, workflow

I'm looking for a software package, addon, or possibly even an internal workflow for Blender 2.8 which will allow me to do in Blender what Railclone can do for 3DsMax. For example, filling a custom shape with custom made tiles. 
Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Does the Particle -> Distribution Grid fill with the Render set to Object work for you?

Comment: @rob I'm not familiar with that yet, I will look it up